# selenium python getting only first image link

Tags: python, selenium

This [product](https://shopnox.com/collections/all/products/the-silk-restraints-of-your-dreams#Media20282964246615) have total five image. I am trying to get those five image links but getting only first image link. here is  my code:

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#shopify-section-product-template .Image--lazyLoaded')

for image in images:
    image = image.get_attribute('data-original-src')
```

**#data-original-src contains link of each image**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is initially loaded with 1 image only.
To get more images you have to scroll the page.
So without scrolling the page, getting the images with

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#shopify-section-product-template .Image--lazyLoaded')
```

will have only 1 element in `images` list.
**UPD**
You can click on the dot's navigation on the left side and then get the image:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Product__SlideshowNavScroller")))
time.sleep(0.2)
dots = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.Product__SlideshowNavScroller a')
image_src = set()
for dot in dots:
    dot.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#shopify-section-product-template .Image--lazyLoaded')
    for image in images:
        image_src.add(image.get_attribute('data-original-src'))
```

`image_src` will finally contain all the images src links

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening here, is that the images are not rendered. To fix that, simply add a code snippet that will scroll to the bottom of the page, before the "find_element" function gets called.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 990000)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting them all because their classes are different.
you will get first image with this:

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#shopify-section-product-template .Image--lazyLoaded')
```

but to get other four use : .Image--fadeIn class